# What's the verb for "cooking" pizza?

Tags: single-word-requests, food

If you make pizza from scratch and put it in your oven, what's the most natural/predominant verb for what you're doing to the pizza? Cooking? Baking? Firing? Something else? None of these sounds entirely right to me (native English speaker), and my friends and Google results don't give a clear answer. I often see variation on a single web page between "cooking" and "baking."

I'm not concerned with the preparing, chopping, or kneading that comes before putting it in the oven. I just want to know what you're doing to the pizza while it's in the oven.

Comment: Are you referring to the entire process, from chopping up the mushrooms, onions, peppers etc, grating the cheese, to putting the whole thing in the oven and then removing it? If you are, then the only word I can think of is "preparing".

Comment: Not the chopping etc. Just what you're doing to the pizza while it's in the oven.

Comment: You're *making* the pizza. As you yourself just said without even noticing. That's how natural it is.

Comment: Making the pizza includes kneading the dough, cutting the mushrooms, etc. I'm looking for the verb specific to the cooking process. As part of making bread, you bake it. As part of making pizza, you ? it.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Domino's online order tracking system uses "bake".

Comment: While not exactly definitive, there is a US restaurant chain *Papa Murphy's Take N' Bake Pizza*. They *make* the pizza and you take it home and *bake* it.

Comment: In general stoves/ranges cook things.  Ovens bake things.  And wood/coal-fired ovens can either fire or bake things.  I think *fire* is more often used in high-temperature ovens (in the 600-1000 degF range) “Cooking” things in an oven really grates on my ears.

Answer (score 33):

I work for a pizza chain and we always just say *cook*.

Technically, the method of cooking is *baking* as that means "place in a hot chamber for a period of time". Other words, such as *boil*, *roast*, etc. have different meanings.

But people often use vocabulary appropriate to the type of food. They often talk about *roasting* meat because that is how meat used to be cooked, even if they are actually *baking* it.

*Roast* is related to *rotate*. *Roasting* meant turning something (usually meat) in front of, or over, the fire. Fat would drip off. This would be collected and poured back on. This is called basting. Potatoes etc. could be out in the tray that was collecting the fat, and thus get heated by the fire while being basted. Thus the term *roast* has been extended from "rotate" to "cook while pouring oil/fat over", or even "cook in a method that replaces roasting". Thus *baked potatoes* are baked without fat, but *roast potatoes* are baked with fat.

This is distinct from *frying*. In *roasting* the oil is there just for succulence, flavour, etc., but in *frying* the oil is heated and this is what cooks the food.

*Bake* is the traditional term for bread, cakes and biscuits, i.e. the things made by a baker. Pizza is a type of bread so *bake* is the correct term, however you look at it.

Some people may use terminology to reflect their particular process, e.g. *fire* to imply that their oven is particularly hot or contains flames.

It is also worth noting that a modern oven is heated while it is cooking, making it a much more flexible machine. Originally, you had to light a fire in the oven to heat it (so the oven was *fired*, not the food), then, when the fire was out, it was removed (so the food was not covered in too much smoke, ash and soot) and then the food was *baked*.

Comment: The difference between baking and roasting is that the application of heat is doing different things. In one case, the starch granules of the flour are being gelatinized; in the other, the protein fibres of the meat are being broken into shorter chain lengths.

Comment: @NigelJ I don't believe this is correct - even if it does tend to hold true. Baked fish for example, involves breaking down proteins the same as roasting chicken. From dictionary definitions, the only *real* difference seems to be (in the context of an oven) that baking is most common for certain foods, roasting is more common for others. Potatoes are even more of an anomaly; as a "baked potato" and "roast potato" really only differs in how they are prepared, not how the heat is applied (or what the heat does).

Comment: 'Roast' potato is a mis-nomer. 'Burnt potato' would be closer to the truth.

Comment: @NigelJ you are roasting them wrong, mine are never burnt

Comment: @WendyG  In that case, _bon appetit_.

Comment: @NigelJ I'm not aware that they had any idea what was actually happening when these terms were invented. They clearly refer to what you do, not what a chemist says happens.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I would not agree. Although the chemistry was not known, the process is clearly different and obviously requires distinct terms.

Comment: Very interesting, @NigelJ. You say "requires" in the present tense. Suggesting what is needed now may differ from when these terms were coined. It is true that terms do get redefined to reflect modern understanding and classification. Some people say that *saki* is no longer *rice wine*, but *rice beer*. And *tidal waves* are no longer *tidal waves* - they are *tsunamis*. Actual usage will vary between the traditional meaning and the more modern classification, but I am not aware that anyone has yet redefined these cooking terms, except, perhaps, in a very technical context.

Comment: My meaning @DavidRobinson was in the past development of the language. My present tense was in a continuous context - it was ever thus.

Comment: "Wood fired" would be a chic term of baking these days and would denote baking on a stone type surface, often a rotating one, over an actual flame rather than a heating element (sometimes with the type of wood fueling the fire chosen for flavor impact e.g. "apple wood fired").

Comment: Re: "*Roast* is related to *rotate*": [citation needed]. The OED identifies various Germanic cognates, but beyond that just says "further etymology uncertain and disputed".

Comment: This is a good answer. In a comment to the OP I provided the main OED definition of *bake*.  Here is that of *roast*. The main difference, so far as using a modern oven is concerned is to do with the application of oil/fat. 
  
 *a. transitive.To cook (food, esp. meat) by prolonged exposure to heat at or before a fire or similar source of radiant heat. Also intransitive.
In early use applied to the method of cooking meat over an open fire, typically on a spit. Later also used of cooking in an enclosed oven, typically with the use of fat; cf. bake v. 1a.*

Comment: You forgot one term from the modern era (although you may have mentally blocked it out)... "microwaved".

Comment: @user3067860 You wouldn't microwave pizza, would you? They don't provide a crisp end product. Soggy pizza - yuk!

Comment: @WS2 I plead the fifth, but I'll point out the number of frozen pizza boxes in the office recycling, and we haven't got an oven (not even a toaster oven).

Comment: @ruakh. I retract my claim. I meant "*roast* is plausibly related to *rota* as roasting almost always involved rotation. The word is of Germanic origin, and as the ultimate root has not been identified, and as it has both semantic and phonological similarity to  *rota*, it could be cognate. It could of course be that the phonological similarity has led to semantic confusion, with *rota* and *roster* often being interchangeable, but I do not accept the https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roster view that *roster* derives semantically from *gridiron*.

Comment: @user3067860 I might need to plead the fifth when it comes to what happens to any pizza that a customer fails to collect and I get to take home. But seriously, you remind me that physicists identify three main ways of heating something: radiation, that includes toasting and microwaving, convection, that includes most baking, and conduction, used in frying, and in ovens where the food touches the floor of the oven. I am talking about the main method in each device - there will always be some heating by each method in each device.

Answer (score 13):

I suspect that this answer will reflect regional diversity, but I always use "bake".

Supermarkets and certain pizzerias sell uncooked pizzas to *bake* yourself at home, i.e.

- https://www.papamurphys.com -- chain store selling uncooked pizza to bake at home
- https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-homemade-frozen-pizza-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-186527 - how to bake a tasty frozen pizza

(Disclaimer: URLs selected to reflect language usage, no promotion implied.  Pineapple and anchovies are both tasty but not on the same pizza, please.)

Comment: Donnow about pineapples -maybe the acid won't sit well- but anchovies with condensed milk over a slice of bread is a really [yummi Spanish recipe](http://www.ilovetapas.com/2011/07/anchoas-con-leche-condensada-receta/) :)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another answer is "firing". Why? Because the pizza chain (Blaze) makes an issue of the fact that they put it in a fire oven at a really high temperature.

But most of the time we use "baking" which is decently covered already.

Comment: I believe the reason your answer isn’t upvoted, is because you are arguing anecdotally; one pizza chain choosing a word such as this, could equally well be a way of branding themselves as different, better or what-have-you from their competitors, much the same as Burger King’s ‘flame-grilled’ ads.

Comment: There are other chains in other places that brag about their "oven-fired" pizzas.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about Pizza, in Italian we say "Infornare" which translate directly to "Baking", so i guess is the most correct answer

Comment: Why is it the most correct? Just because it's directly translated as such from Italian doesn't make it the best choice in English.

Comment: Why would you say the contrary? Since Italians created the Pizza i assume the term they (we) use is the correct one, especially when there is a direct translation for it in English.

Comment: Who says *infornare* translates as "bake". If the correct Italian term is *infornare* then it follows that the whole of this discussion is about what is the English for *infornare*. But it can be pointed out that if we take the word apart then it becomes in-forn-are, in-oven-to, or "to put in the oven". That would solve a lot of argument!

Answer (score 0):

Baking. Firing if using a large-style gas or coal or wood oven. Cooking isn't entirely inappropriate.

Comment: Please explain why your answer is correct.

Comment: ...and why simple reposting the verb offered by [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/468425/15679) a day after it was posted is useful.

Comment: Duplicate answers can be useful. It often depends more on the usefulness of the explanation than the answer itself. To show that yours is the right answer, consider adding explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes answers useful – to the asker, and to future visitors. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.